# TestNG: Method requires 2 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am a newbie to selenium testing. 
Basically, 
I have a selenium class like :

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.google.common.base.Function;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SeleniumTests {

    public void commonFunction(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Downloads//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver();
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        driver.get("http://localhost:3000");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        test1(driver,builder);
    }
    //The driver,builder will be used by all the below 3 test functions.

    /**
     * Calling the Most Visited API -- TEST1
     */
    public void test1(WebDriver driver,Actions builder){
        WebElement most_visited_link = driver.findElement(By.id("mostVisited"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        Action mouseOvermost_visited_link = builder.moveToElement(most_visited_link).build();
        mouseOvermost_visited_link.perform(); 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("mostVisited")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement most_Visited_button = driver.findElement(By.id("datePicked"));
        Action mouse_most_VisitedOverDatePicker = builder.moveToElement(most_Visited_button).build();
        mouse_most_VisitedOverDatePicker.perform(); 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("datePicked")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("6")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        test2(driver,builder);
    }

    /**
     * Calling the Status Pie API  -- TEST2
     * @param builder 
     * @param driver 
     */
    public void test2(WebDriver driver,Actions builder){
        WebElement status_pie_link = driver.findElement(By.id("statusPie"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Action mouseOverStatusPie = builder.moveToElement(status_pie_link).build();
        mouseOverStatusPie.perform(); 
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("statusPie")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement status_pie_button = driver.findElement(By.id("datePicked"));
        Action mouseOver_Status_pie_DatePicker = builder.moveToElement(status_pie_button).build();
        mouseOver_Status_pie_DatePicker.perform(); 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("datePicked")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("6")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        test3(driver,builder);
    }

    /**
     * Calling the Old Data API -- TEST3
     */
    public void test2(WebDriver driver,Actions builder){
        WebElement old_data_link = driver.findElement(By.id("oldData"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Action mouseOverOldData = builder.moveToElement(old_data_link).build();
        mouseOverOldData.perform(); 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("oldData")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement old_data_button = driver.findElement(By.id("datePicked"));
        Action mouseOverDatePicker = builder.moveToElement(old_data_button).build();
        mouseOverDatePicker.perform(); 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("datePicked")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("6")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

The code executes as expected on the browser and closes the chrome window. 
However, in the index report, I see log as :

```
3 methods, 2 skipped, 1 passed 
Skipped methods :    
 mostVisitedfunction   
 statuspiefunction   

Passed methods :    
 createConnection
```

Any idea where am I going wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method mostVisitedfunction should not have annotation because it is the helping method for yoyr test case. Instead create a new class, create a object of the same in the @test class and then call that method..

See the below example..

My test is

```
//MAximize the Screen
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
//Go to Gmail Login Page
    SignInPage SignInPage = WebUtils.GoToSignInPage(driver);
//Sign in to Login page -Send Username 
    SignInPage.SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='Email']") , "kishanpatelllll.8@gmail.com" );
//Click on Next
    SignInPage.ClickToLogin(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='next']"));
//Wait for password field to be visible
    SignInPage.WaitForElementTobeVisible(driver, By.cssSelector("input[id='Passwd'][type='password']"));
```

So when i call the method SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge i wont write it in @Test.

See SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge  method:
public class SignInPage {

```
public void SendkeysMethodForSignInPAge(WebDriver driver, By by, String s) {
    WebUtils.Sendkeys(driver,by,s);
}
```

I created a new class and there i defined it.
This is basic flow.
Hope you can relate this.
Reply to me, if your are still stuck.
Happy Learning :-)

Comment: Hi Kishan, 
Thank you for the help and concern . 
While being a newbie to selenium, I am really unable to figure out how my base methods and the test methods will work. 
I have edited and updated my src code. 
Can you please help me according to my code. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using actions everywhere? see your link http://localhost:3000 is a localhost so i cannot run it on eclipse and solve your problem.  You donot need to use actions to click. You can just go to the Webelement and perform click by clickmethod. 
Now you might come up with question that then where can i use actions?
So actions are use for e.g. there is some hovering which results into some more options which are clickable.

Comment: So there we can use the action.movetoelement(element).buil().perform(); Hope you are getting me. If not, then tell me i will share a code which will make it easy to relate how to write test case in selenium. Happy Learning :-)

Answer (score 1):

The error comes because if you have parameters in your @Test annotated method, then those need to come from @Parameters or @DataProvider.  Else, if none of the annotation supplies the arguments, which is your case, then the error is thrown.

Apart from that what @Kishan has suggested in terms of structure of code is correct.  You need to differentiate between your tests and common functions.

Comment: Hi Neha, Thank you for the help and concern . While being a newbie to selenium, I am really unable to figure out how my base methods and the test methods will work. I have edited and updated my src code. Can you please help me according to my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test 
public void assertBackToLogin(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
    LoginPage login = new  LoginPage (driver); 
    login.assertLogin();
}
```

**Is NOT working**

Remove all the **parameters** and **run**

```
@Test 
public void assertBackToLogin() throws InterruptedException {
    LoginPage login = new  LoginPage (driver); 
    login.assertLogin();
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `driver` be undefined inside the method?